# extracting table with htmltab R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to scrape the second table from 
[https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/passing/Premier-League-Stats](http://fbref.com/en/comps/9/passing/Premier-League-Stats)

I have used

```
URLPL <- "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/passing/Premier-League-Stats"
Tab <- htmltab(doc = URLPL, which = 2)
```

which returns

> "Error: Couldn't find the table. Try passing (a different) information
>   to the which argument"

and also

```
URLPL <- "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/passing/Premier-League-Stats"
Tab <- htmltab(doc = URLPL, which = "//table[2]")
```

which returns

> "Error in Node[[1](http://fbref.com/en/comps/9/passing/Premier-League-Stats)] : subscript out of bounds"

There is 2 tables on the webpage. If anyone can point me on the right path here. 
Thanks.

Edit: I've now realised that there's only 1 table on the webpage and what I thought was a table, is not. Now I'm even more confused as where to go with this.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here. For anyone who may have the same problem. 
Anything other than the top table on any of the sports-references websites. (Hockey/Basketball/Baseball) are counted as comments.

```
PremLeague = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/12/stats/La-Liga-Stats"

 Prem  =  PremLeague %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//comment()') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  paste(collapse='') %>%  
  read_html() %>%
  html_node("#stats_standard") %>%  
  html_table()
```

This worked for me.